# Use sed to replace full stop with full stop followed by space

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace a full stop in the title field (field2) of a csv with a full stop followed by a space:

csv example:

```
8389383, hello my.friend,839083083,3390903
```

Intended output:

```
8389383, hello my. friend,839083083,3390903
```

I can successfully replace a full stop in a csv with a space only using this line:

```
sed -r ':b s/^([^,]*,[^,]*)\./\1 /g; t b' csv
```

However, I want to replace the full stop with a full stop followed by a space. I've tried:

```
sed -r ':b s/^([^,]*,[^,]*)\./\1. /g; t b' csv
```

But this hangs and doesn't produce a result.

What can I add to the line to allow this?

EDIT- Just to add, there may be more than one full stop in field 2 (the title field) that I want to replace. I also don't want this rule to apply to any other fields in the csv.

Comment: might as well add sample input/output that better reflects your requirement so that others can easily test :)

Comment: It doesn't stop because it hasn't finished adding hundreds of thousands of millions of billions of spaces after the full stop.  When it first matches, it adds a blank; the test is true, so it goes back and tries again, finds a stop, adds a blank, and … it gets boring after a while.  You probably want some trailing context after the stop — a non-blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` is best suited for these kind of jobs

For a replacing **all the full-stops** in the second field do

```
 awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," '{gsub(/\./,". ",$2)}1' file.csv > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file.csv

8389383, hello my. friend,839083083,3390903
8389383, hello my. fri. end,839083083,3390903
```

Comment: awk seems the best choice here as we can selectively apply `g` flag for second field

Comment: @spasic did you meant with `gensub`. Neither `sub` nor `gsub` has it as you're probably aware. Using `gensub`, though, makes the script less portable.

Comment: @sjsam Ok, this is looking like it might do the trick, but first- I'm not not too familiar with awk- can it render the result straight to the file in a similar way to `sed -i` ?

Comment: @bms9nmh  There is an inplace edit in the a recent version of `gawk` but that is less portable. Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I find out? I'm running my script on a Synology box which is a stripped down debian style linux.

Comment: @sjsam, am still not that familiar with awk.. I meant `g` as in replace all matches as opposed to `sub()`..

Comment: @spasic : I see, I thought about the the `g` flag with `gensub` as in `gensub("/\./,". ","g","$2")`. :)

Comment: @sjsam - no unfortunately this line is now not replacing any of the full stops unlike the output before the edit

Comment: @sjsam - this is now also replacing the commas seperating the fields with full stops

Comment: @bms9nmh : Sorry I accidentally put `-v OFS="."` instead of `-v OFS=","`. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\([^,]*,[^.,]*\)\.\([^,]*\)/\1. \2/' file.csv
```

**Edit** If you have multiple full stops in the field, you cannot do it with `sed`. Here's a `perl` one-liner though:

```
perl -i -pe 'sub t {($s)=@_; $s=~s/\./. /g; $s}; s/^[^,]*,\K([^,]*)/t($1)/e;' file.csv
```

Explanation: With the `s///` command, we find the first field (`[^,]*,`), we skip it (`\K`), and then we find the second field (`([^,]*)`). For that field, we execute the function `t` which does a simple substation.

Comment: Hi, this only replaces this first full stop. If there are more that one in the second field it doesn't seem to replace them.

Comment: @bms9nmh : Using `sed` is indeed laborious for the job.

Comment: @bms9nmh Sorry, I missed your edit in the question. I added a `perl` based solution to my answer. It cannot be done with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^([^,]*,[^,.]*)\./\1\n/;ta;s/\n/. /g' file
```

The trick here is to turn the `.` into `something else` (I favour the newline character as it is unique by seds design) and then globally change that `something else` to `whatever` as the last operation on the line.

An alternative is to copy the line, change a piece and recombine the line using the parts from the copy that you don't want to change:

```
sed -r 's/,/\n/;s/,/\n/;h;s/\./& /g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2,\1,/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file.csv 
8389383, hello my.friend, 839083083, 3390903
8389383, hello my.fri.end, 839083083, 3390903

$ perl -i -F, -e '$F[1] =~ s/\./. /g; print join(",",@F)' file.csv 

$ cat file.csv 
8389383, hello my. friend, 839083083, 3390903
8389383, hello my. fri. end, 839083083, 3390903
```

- `-F,` split each line on `,` and saves it in `@F` array. `-F` option implicitly sets `-a` and `-n` as well. See [perldoc Command Switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for further reading
- `join(",",@F)` join the array with `,` as separator. Don't know if there is an implicit way in perl to print the modified array with same input separator